# A weird thing of Magento breadcrumbs?

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

```
<ul>
    <li class="home">
    <a title="Go to Home Page" href="#">Home</a>
    <span>/ </span>
    </li>
    <li class="category3">New Arrival<span>/ </span>
    </li>
    <li class="cms_page"><strong></strong>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Above is the html code of site breadcrumbs. Why do my template breadcrumbs add this code `<li class="cms_page"><strong></strong></li>`? All the code in the breadcrumbs.phtml of the base template are the same when i change the theme to default. There is no

```
<li class="cms_page"><strong></strong>
        </li>
```

What's wrong with my template? thank you

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are editing the right template? To verify that turn on template hints from `system > configuration > developer`

Comment: yes,the template file i edited is right. now i commented $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('cms_page', array('label'=>$page->getTitle(), 'title'=>$page->getTitle() this line in cms/block/page.php. it's ok. do you know why? thank u